# Search filter using a bean's field values

Tags: jsf, ejb

Given a JSF/EJB stack, how do I filter the contents of a dataTable listing automatically using the values of a field in a pojo/entity bean?

i.e. I have an entity bean Employee with name field having a value of "John" I would like to use this bean to filter the data table to show only records with name John, and not having to construct the where clause manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `PrimeFaces'` dataTable with filtering and eventually lazy-Loading. Filtering alone is done at a client level, but lazy-loading is done at a server level.

[Here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableHome.jsf) you can find some examples.

Both are implemented with Ajax features by PrimeFaces: on typing each character, the filters are applied and the results updated.

With PrimeFaces' lazy-loading you have also the possibility to handle by yourself the filters: on typing a character in a filter, your implementation of the filter is invoked: with a little of Criteria Builder queries you can write the WHERE conditions in a type-safe and OO way, by building an array of `Predicates`: this implies that you don't need to write a single line of sql code.